# Should _set have pair method __isset?

Tags: php

I've got a class with magic methods `__get` and `__set`, but without an `__isset` method. Not the exact code, but just to get an idea of what it's like:

```
class TestCase
{
    #[OneToMany]
    private \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $properties;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $property = $this->properties->filter(fn ($property) => $property->getName() === $name);

        if ($property->count() === 1) {
            $property->first()->setValue($value);
            return $this;
        }

        $this->properties->add(new Property($name, $value));

        return $this;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $property = $this->properties->filter(fn ($property) => $property->getName() === $name);

        if ($property->count() === 1) {
            return $property->first();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using the [Php Inspections (EA Extended)](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea) plugin and it tells me:

> __set should have pair method __isset

Why should I have that method? In my case, I use `__set` to set a value, even if it already exist. And if I add an `__isset` method, it runs the `$this->properties->filter(...`) part twice. So  from a performance point of view, it's even getting worse.

Can anybody explain if (and if so: why?) an `__isset` magic method is recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread on it [here](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/issues/912) and the [documented reason here](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/blob/master/docs/probable-bugs.md#emptyisset-results-correctness).

*Not* implementing this would be like having an array that doesn’t support `array_key_exists`. *You* might know all of the keys, but other users or consumers of your code would expect the array to function just like other arrays.

This isn’t a right or wrong thing, just the opinion of the tool.

Reading through the issue, there also appears to be a general preference for avoiding dynamic properties on objects, something I also agree with but still occasionally have a need for. Still just an opinion, but remember that the opinion is coming from a tool that is trying to help you write “the best” code possible.

The idea is that it is easier to reason about classes with defined fields instead of relying on hidden/magic logic through `__get` and `__set`. Your code isn’t wrong, but the tooling can’t help you as much because you have taken a first class language construct, which includes default values, types, documentation, etc., and are doing “something else”. Maybe you are passing through, one-for-one. But maybe you also know that certain items need casting or parsing.